# Do while can do this but I want to know why this is wrong

Tags: c, generics, compilation, scanf, clion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rpcndr.h>



int main() {
    boolean playAgain=1;
    char playInput;
    float num1,num2,answer;

    char operator;

    while (playAgain){
        printf("Enter First Number, operator, second number:");
        scanf("%f%c%f",&num1,&operator,&num2);

        switch (operator) {
            case '*':
                answer=(num1*num2);
                break;
            case '/':
                answer=(num1/num2);
                break;
            case '+':
                answer=num1+num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                answer=num1-num2;
                break;
            default:break;
        }
        printf("%f\n",answer);
        printf("Do You Want To Try It Again(y/n)?");
        scanf("%c",&playInput);
        if(playInput=='n'){
            playAgain=0;
        }
    }




}
```

Do while can do this code. But I want to why this method gets an error. And there is a problem with Scanf() function.
Error says :
Clang-Tidy: 'scanf' used to convert a string to a floating-point value, but function will not report conversion errors; consider using 'strtof' instead

Comment: Not sure 100% but the problem may be the dense (i mean jammed) format specifiers in the `scanf`. Try, after inserting spaces between num1 / operator / num2 both in the `scanf` (like `"%f %c %f"`) and your input.

Comment: The warning you're getting from clang-tidy is probably due to not checking the return value of `scanf` to see if it succeeded or not.

Comment: The `scanf("%c", &playInput);` should be `scanf(" %c", &playInput);` with added space. And so should `scanf("%f%c%f", &num1, &operator, &num2);` be `scanf("%f %c%f", &num1, &operator, &num2);` with added space.

Comment: Why? The `scanf` conversion stops at the first character it cannot convert, which is typically (but not necessarily) a space or a newline, and that character remains in the input buffer. It will be read by the *next* `scanf()` format specifier. Format specifiers `%d` and `%s` and `%f` automatically filter such leading whitespace characters, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. You can instruct `scanf` to do so by adding a space just before the `%`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues.

The first `scanf` won't check for syntax errors in the numbers and may leave a newline in the stream and confuse the second `scanf`

The *second* `scanf` *may* not strip the newline from the stream, so on the second loop iteration, the *first* `scanf` may have a problem.

While it *might* be possible to fix/contort `scanf` into doing what you want, I'd follow clang's warning and use `strtof`.

Here's the code refactored to use `fgets` and `strtof`. It is annotated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <rpcndr.h>

// lineget -- get a line from user with prompt
// RETURNS: pointer to buffer (NULL means EOF)
char *
lineget(char *buf,size_t len,const char *prompt)
{
    char *cp;

    // output prompt to user
    puts(prompt);
    fflush(stdout);

    do {
        // get an input line
        cp = fgets(buf,len,stdin);

        // got EOF
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // strip newline
        buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;
    } while (0);

    return cp;
}

int
main(void)
{
    float num1, num2, answer;
    char *cp;
    char buf[1000];
    int err;

    char operator;

    while (1) {
        cp = lineget(buf,sizeof(buf),
            "Enter First Number, operator, second number:");
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // get the first number
        num1 = strtof(cp,&cp);

        // get the operator
        // NOTE: this could be a syntax error for the first number -- we'll
        // check that below in the switch
        operator = *cp;
        if (operator != 0)
            ++cp;

        // get second number and check for syntax error
        num2 = strtof(cp,&cp);
        if (*cp != 0) {
            printf("ERROR trailing '%s'\n",cp);
            continue;
        }

        err = 0;
        switch (operator) {
        case '*':
            answer = (num1 * num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            answer = (num1 / num2);
            break;
        case '+':
            answer = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            answer = num1 - num2;
            break;
        default:
            err = 1;
            break;
        }

        // we got a bad operator (or syntax error in first number)
        if (err) {
            printf("ERROR unknown operator '%c'\n",operator);
            continue;
        }

        printf("%f\n", answer);

        cp = lineget(buf,sizeof(buf),"Do You Want To Try It Again(y/n)?");
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;
        if (buf[0] == 'n')
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above code will detect most errors. Here's an enhanced version that does even more explicit checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <rpcndr.h>

// lineget -- get a line from user with prompt
// RETURNS: pointer to buffer (NULL means EOF)
char *
lineget(char *buf,size_t len,const char *prompt)
{
    char *cp;

    // output prompt to user
    puts(prompt);
    fflush(stdout);

    do {
        // get an input line
        cp = fgets(buf,len,stdin);

        // got EOF
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // strip newline
        buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = 0;
    } while (0);

    return cp;
}

int
main(void)
{
    float num1, num2, answer;
    char *cp;
    char *bp;
    char buf[1000];
    int err;

    char operator;

    while (1) {
        bp = lineget(buf,sizeof(buf),
            "Enter First Number, operator, second number:");
        if (bp == NULL)
            break;

        // get the first number
        num1 = strtof(bp,&cp);

        // ensure we got at least a digit
        // NOTE: this will detect:
        //   ""
        //   "j"
        if (cp == bp) {
            printf("ERROR no first number specified\n");
            continue;
        }

        // get the operator
        // NOTE: this could be a syntax error for the first number -- we'll
        // check that below in the switch
        operator = *cp;

        // no operator specified
        if (operator == 0) {
            printf("ERROR no operator specified\n");
            continue;
        }

        // skip over the operator
        bp = ++cp;

        // get second number and check for syntax error
        num2 = strtof(bp,&cp);
        if (*cp != 0) {
            printf("ERROR trailing '%s'\n",cp);
            continue;
        }

        // we need at least one digit (e.g.):
        //   we want to reject: 23+ and ensure we have [at least] 23+0
        //   this will detect 23+k
        if (cp == bp) {
            printf("ERROR no second number specified\n");
            continue;
        }

        err = 0;
        switch (operator) {
        case '*':
            answer = (num1 * num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            answer = (num1 / num2);
            break;
        case '+':
            answer = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            answer = num1 - num2;
            break;
        default:
            err = 1;
            break;
        }

        // we got a bad operator (or syntax error in first number)
        if (err) {
            printf("ERROR unknown operator '%c'\n",operator);
            continue;
        }

        printf("%f\n", answer);

        cp = lineget(buf,sizeof(buf),"Do You Want To Try It Again(y/n)?");
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;
        if (buf[0] == 'n')
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
fflush is undefined behavior, you can use getchar() to clear the buffer

```
#include <stdio.h>


void clear_input_buffer()
{
    char tmp;
    do
    {
        tmp = getchar();
    } while (tmp != '\n' && tmp != EOF);
}

int main()
{
    _Bool playAgain = 1;
    char playInput;
    float num1, num2, answer;
    char operator;


    while (playAgain)
    {
        printf("Enter First Number, operator, second number:");
        scanf("%f%c%f", &num1, &operator, & num2);
        clear_input_buffer();
        switch (operator)
        {
        case '*':
            answer = (num1 * num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            answer = (num1 / num2);
            break;
        case '+':
            answer = num1 + num2;
            break;
        case '-':
            answer = num1 - num2;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        printf("%f\n", answer);
        printf("Do You Want To Try It Again(y/n)?");
        scanf("%c", &playInput);
        clear_input_buffer();
        if (playInput == 'n')
        {
            playAgain = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

OLD:
You should use fflush(stdin) (if your compiler supports it, it is undefinded by c stanard) or a diffrent method to clear the input buffer, otherwise scanf will read an extra \n at the end causing it to skip the rest of the data in the buffer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    _Bool playAgain=1;
    char playInput;
    float num1,num2,answer;

    char operator;

    while (playAgain){
        printf("Enter First Number, operator, second number:");
        scanf("%f%c%f",&num1,&operator,&num2);
        fflush(stdin);
        switch (operator) {
            case '*':
                answer=(num1*num2);
                break;
            case '/':
                answer=(num1/num2);
                break;
            case '+':
                answer=num1+num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                answer=num1-num2;
                break;
            default:break;
        }
        printf("%f\n",answer);
        printf("Do You Want To Try It Again(y/n)?");
        scanf("%c",&playInput);
        fflush(stdin);
        if(playInput=='n'){
            playAgain=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fflush(stdin) is undefined behavior -- it might crash or do nothing.